# Iterating over C string not working

Tags: c, string, iteration

First, my objective with this code: take in a sentence into a C string. Iterate through the sentence and see how many instances of a particular letter occur.

This code is working somewhat but not giving the right number? Not sure why:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int tracker=0;
int letterCount (char *sentence)
{
    int s=strlen(sentence);
    int i=0;


    for (i=0; i<s; i++){
        if (sentence[i]=='h') {
            tracker++;
        }
    }
    return tracker;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    char *string="Hi there, what's going on? How's it going?";


    letterCount(string);

    printf("this sentensce has %i H's", tracker);


    return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting:

```
this sentensce has 2 H's
```

Not quite right. Any ideas?

Comment: It only has 2 `h`, it also only has 2 `H` which is not what you search in your code

Comment: By the way - the brackets inside the "if" are redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code if you mean case insensitive H:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int tracker=0;
int letterCount (char *sentence)
{
    int s=strlen(sentence);
    int i=0;


    for (i=0; i<s; i++){
        if (sentence[i]=='h' || sentence[i]=='H') {  //'h' is not the same as 'H'
            tracker++;
        }
    }
    return tracker;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    char *string="Hi there, what's going on? How's it going?";


    letterCount(string);

    printf("this sentensce has %i H's", tracker);


    return 0;
}
```

You have just mispelled  small and the capital letter in your code.
Remember, the C  language is case sensitive!

Comment: Adding on that the ASCII char representations of 'h' and 'H' are not the same, hence why there is a need to check for both.

Answer (score 0):

Although your label talks about the number of `H`s, your `letterCount` looks for `h`s instead -- and it looks to me like the input you've provided does have two instances of lower-case `h`, just as it says.

If you want to count them together, you might consider filtering each input with `tolower` or `toupper` before checking what you have.

Answer (score 0):

That number looks correct to me: you have 2 'h' characters in that sentence. If you want to count the 'H' characters as well, then you need a separate check.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t letterCount(const char* sentence, char c)
{
  size_t count = 0;

  while(sentence)
  {
    count += (*sentence == c);
    ++sentence;
  }

  return count;
}
```

What do we see here?

- You can't have negative count, so use an unsigned type like size_t
- sentence shouldn't be modified, so it should be const
- pass in the char you want to match
- sentence is a pointer, if it is null you are done.  Don't need to call strlen.
- sentence is a pointer, the actual pointer is pass by value, so you can modify it (see the increment, no need to make an extra variable)
- boolean operators return 1 or 0, so no need to use the if.  (Although, I haven't looked at the assembly to see if an if branch or an add 0 is cheaper. YMMV)